# Passing procedure as a parameter in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have this code >

```
type
  TCallBack = procedure(APerc: Integer) of object;
```

....

```
procedure CallingProcedure(a, b, c: Integer; ACallBack: TCallBack = nil);
```

....

I call this function from my main class/object like this:

```
CallingProcedure(1, 2, 3, DoOnCallBack);
```

where DoOnCallBack is defined as:

```
procedure DoOnCallBack(APerc: Integer);
```

This compiles good, it's not problem - I did this tons of times.

But in CallingProcedure when I want to check if Assigned(ACallBack) I'm getting False.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I'm calling this from Thread, is that might be a problem?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems from what I can see. Can you post a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This compiles?  I don't think so... `DoOnCallback` is a regular procedure - `TCallBack` is defined as `procedure of object`.  Can you post your real code please?

Comment: Two people complained about the code not demonstrating the problem, but neither voted to close. Questions with bogus code are off topic here.

Comment: @RobKennedy Sorry, I usually do - was extremely busy earlier, didn't stay long and it slipped my mind.

Comment: @J..., "I call this function from my main class/object like this: ... where DoOnCallBack is defined as... ". Seems as DoOnCallback is a method. Anyway, without a complete code to demonstrate the problem this question does not make sense.

Comment: @LURD Naturally - I'm quite sure that he's telling us the truth about having code that compiles.  The point is that whatever is posted in the question isn't it.

Comment: "Calling" one thread from another thread can definitively a problem, this is technically impossible. You need to use `TThread::Synchronize` for passing informations between a background thread and the main thread.

Comment: @Wolf The question doesn't talk about calling one thread from another. And there's nothing that says that all cross thread data access must be synchronized. Don't promote mis-information like that. There are many ways for threads to interact. Oranges are not the only fruit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know that there are many ways for threads to interact, but this style of question *`I'm calling this from Thread, is that might be a problem?`* reminds me of lots of questions I had to deal with where I finally discovered that the asker wasn't aware what threads are.

Comment: @wolf Threading is indeed quite likely relevant here. But blanket advice like *"you need to use `TThread.Synchronize`"* is very unhelpful and misleading.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right. But I also tried to force the asker to add more details. Let's wait and see...

Comment: I'm very sorry for inconvenience and stupid question. This code works perfectly - but after 14+ hours of coding I didn't realize that I'm calling function from another place where default was always NIL... Sorry for your time and thanks for answers!!

Answer (score 4):

I makes no diffrence from where you call it. The syntax is the same. I've just made this small test example :

```
type
  TCallBack = procedure(APerc: Integer) of object;
  TForm20 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure CallingProcedure(a, b, c: Integer; ACallBack: TCallBack = nil);
    procedure DoOnCallBack(APerc: Integer);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form20: TForm20;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm20.CallingProcedure(a, b, c: Integer; ACallBack: TCallBack);
begin
  if Assigned(ACallBack) then
    ACallBack(a);
end;

procedure TForm20.DoOnCallBack(APerc: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(APerc));
end;

procedure TForm20.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CallingProcedure(1, 2, 3, DoOnCallBack);
  CallingProcedure(1, 2, 3, nil);
end;
```

And it works just fine. Ajust you code to look like this. Since you haven't posted your real code I can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: I'm very sorry for inconvenience and stupid question. This code works perfectly - but after 14+ hours of coding I didn't realize that I'm calling function from another place where default was always NIL... Sorry for your time and thanks for answers!!