# How to pass on parameters in procedure parameter ('nested')?

Tags: delphi, parameters, procedure, delphi-10.3-rio

I had this:

```
type
  TFuncGetData = function: Integer of object;

function TFrmAPI.GetExactData(AFunc: TFuncGetData): Integer;
var lStatus: Integer;
begin
  FErrorMsg := '';
  lStatus   := AFunc;
  ...
```

and then a bunch of `TFuncGetData` like this

```
function TFrmAPI.GetCurrentDivision: Integer;
begin
  ...
```

getting called:

```
lResult := GetExactData(GetCurrentDivision);
```

---

It now turns out that all these `TFuncGetData` need a parameter to pass information:

```
type
  TFuncGetData = function(ASelProps: TSelectionProperties): Integer of object;  

function TFrmAPI.GetCurrentDivision(ASelProps: TSelectionProperties): Integer;
begin
  ...
```

but function `GetExactData` now chokes on the `lStatus :=aFunc` call with `E2035 Not enough actual parameters`.

I see two ways to solve this:

- Define a `TFrmAPI.FSelectionProperties`, set that and let `GetExactData` use that
- Pass the TSelectionProperties with the call (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337521/passing-procedure-as-a-parameter-in-delphi)):

.

```
function TFrmAPI.GetExactData(AFunc: TFuncGetData; ASelProps: TSelectionProperties): Integer;
var lStatus: Integer;
begin
  FErrorMsg := '';
  lStatus   := AFunc(ASelProps);
```

The second method is safer (because potential overwrites of TFrmAPI.FSelectionProperties), but would there be an other better way to construct this?

Comment: Personally, I would use second method, because it is more readable. It is also useful if you have no need to store `ASelProps` after executing `GetExactData` method. Besides, you will be able to pass *any* data with your `ASelProps` in a case if amount of arguments will be changed in the future.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to have the `ASelProps` parameter of the `GetExactData` method optional? Or what is the aim (you say *"all these TFuncGetData need a parameter"* which is what you already have)?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a "global" variable to be passed to the function gets in your way once the calls start to get recursive, or even when the object is used in multiple threads.

Augmenting your method with an additional parameter has only advantages:

- recursive calls can still use different values
- you could make it optional, providing a default value (`Method( f: TFunc; p: TParam= 0 ): Integer;`)
- for being futureproof/unbound, define your own type (i.e. a record that could be extended at a later time easily, or a type that is directly assigned to another like `type TParam= Cardinal;`)
- the oldschool/hazardous approach would be to just use pointers, which allows you to hand over anything (I don't recommend this, situations which needs you to be this flexible are rare)